# ASF (Apache Software Foundation) 2.0 licence

Tags: apache, foundation, complex-event-processing

I have to select one of the following tools for developing an event processing part of a project, but this tool should be under the ASF 2.0 license.

- [SIDDHI](http://siddhi.sourceforge.net/) >> under ASF licence
- [ETALIS](http://code.google.com/p/etalis/) >> under GNU Lesser GPL licence
- [JBoss – Drools Fusion](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-fusion.html) >> ASL license
- [ActiveInsight](http://java-source.net/open-source/j2ee-frameworks/activeinsight) >> Common Public Attribution License 1.0 (CPAL)
- [Intelligent Event Processor – IEP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21454_01/html/821-2611/index.html)
- [SQLstream](http://www.sqlstream.com/)
- [Oracle Event Processing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/complex-event-processing/overview/index.html)

I know the four firs, How can I check the others?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Event Processing is a proprietary product and doesn't come with an ASF/open-source license. Same applies for IEP.

SQLstream also appears to be a proprietary product with a 60-day trail license. Pls see
http://www.sqlstream.com/docs/pdf/3.0.0/SQLstream_Getting_Started_Guide_V3.0.0.pdf